# Cloth sim not working clothes t-shirt tshirt gravity

Tags: cloth-simulation

I've modelled a very basic tshirt:

[image]

Fully modelled (no stitching), large enough and spaced far enough to not be colliding with a collision body in initial state. Upon playing the timeline the tshirt moves down very slightly (like very minute almost like a frame glitch) in Z and nothing happens, it doesn't respond to gravity, it doesn't crumple, nothing. Ive tried:

1. Applying scale and rotation, even all transforms on both tshirt and body meshes.
2. As the quads in the mesh are very basic at the moment and large I tried subdiving 8 times until the quads were small, no difference.
3. Checked gravity is on in the main Blender settings, it was off but switching it back on makes no difference. Changing gravity intensity or direction does nothing.
4. Even deleted the body mesh, the tshirt reacts the same exact way upon playing the timeline.
5. Recalculated normals on the tshirt and checked the body, all normals are correct and pointing outward.
6. Checked the vertices of the tshirt, there are no duplicates or unstitched vertices, no mirror modifier is active on it, it is one complete mesh.
7. Changed cloth settings under stiffness and damping, set them to high and low values (zero), no difference.
8. Increased cloth quality steps, no difference.
9. Enabled and disabled springs, no change.
10. Collision quality higher.
11. Object collisions distance to the lowest 0.001.
12. Enabled and disabled self collisions.
13. Changed the vertex masses to numerous numbers, makes no difference.

The only modifier on the tshirt is the cloth one. I really don't know what else to do.

I did try the cloth as panels initially then relying on stitching first but it doesn't work well and still had the issue of it not responding to gravity.

This is a very basic sim, if it ever works I'll need to subdivide it a lot and animate collisions with it (upper arms) to blend with a live plate.

Answer (score 0):

Think I've sorted it, need to tweak the cloth settings to make it more like the material I want, but the main issue was not baking the simulation, gravity doesn't seem to work without doing this.

Also adjusted the collision distance of the cloth to 0.002 and of the collision object to 0.02 outer and collisions seem to be working.